# Is there a name for this compression algorithm?

Tags: compression

Say you have a four byte integer and you want to compress it to fewer bytes. You are able to compress it because smaller values are more probable than larger values (i.e., the probability of a value decreases with its magnitude). You apply the following scheme, to produce a 1, 2, 3 or 4 byte result:

Note that in the description below (the bits are one-based and go from most significant to least significant), i.e., the first bit refers to most significant bit, the second bit to the next most significant bit, etc...)

1. If n<128, you encode it as a
   single byte with the first bit set
   to zero
2. If n>=128 and n<16,384 ,
   you use a two byte integer. You set
   the first bit to one, to indicate
   and the second bit to zero. Then you
   use the remaining 14 bits to encode
   the number n.
3. If n>16,384 and
   n<2,097,152 , you use a three byte
   integer. You set the first bit to
   one, the second bit to one, and the
   third bit to zero. You use the
   remaining 21 bits, to encode n.
4. If n>2,097,152 and n<268,435,456 ,
   you use a four byte integer. You set
   the first three bits to one and the
   fourth bit to zero. You use the
   remaining 28 bits to encode n.
5. If n>=268,435,456 and n<4,294,967,296,
   you use a five byte integer. You set
   the first four bits to one and use
   the following 32-bits to set the
   exact value of n, as a four byte
   integer. The remainder of the bits is unused.

Is there a name for this algorithm?

Comment: I like this! But this will break the functionality of pointers... The pointer will have to read the first bits of the value pointed to to know where the next value will be.. But it certainly sounds nice, haven't heard of it.

Comment: This scheme is very similar to UTF-8.

Comment: I believe I've seen a draft RFC that proposed this scheme for transmitting arbitrary precision integers, but my Google-fu fails me. In any case, you won't get it patented :)

Comment: Aha: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity

Comment: The difference between Michael Goldshteyn's algorithm and UTF-8 is that the latter "wastes" bits to make it possible to efficiently find the beginning of a character that uses any given byte of the string. Specifically, each byte after the first is of the form 10xxxxxx.

Comment: larsmans, submit your comment as an answer - you will get the checkmark for hitting it right on the nose.

Comment: @larsmans, VLQ is very different than @Michael Goldshteyn's algorithm, but thanks for reminding me of that scheme. With the OP's scheme, you know how many bytes the value occupies by reading the first byte. (It uses a header.) That's not the case for the VLQ. (It uses a terminator.)

Comment: @ikegami: Having read the Wiki page and http://www.dlugosz.com/ZIP2/VLI.html, the OP's scheme seems more similar to VLQ than to Dlugosz' encoding.

Comment: @larsmans, According to that link, Dlugosz's starts the same as the OP, but it diverges for 4 and 5 byte sequences. I agree that they are different. I don't agree that VLQ is more similar, though. VLQ and Michael Goldshteyn's algorithm have different benefits.

Comment: see: http://ebml.sourceforge.net/specs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite close to [variable-length quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) encoding or base-128. The latter name stems from the fact that each 7-bit unit in your encoding can be considered a base-128 digit.

Comment: As previously mentioned, that's not true. Wikipedia says the VLQ of 3FFF is `FF 7F`. Using @Michael Goldshteyn's algorithm, 3FFF is `C0 3F FF`.

Comment: @ikegami: reread the description and you're right: I missed some of the details, including that the length is prepended in base-1, rather than "threaded through" the representation of the integer.

Comment: Although larsmans answer is not identical to my proposed algorithm, it is in the spirit of the question and the closest (actual existing) algorithm. Therefore he got the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

it sounds very similar to Dlugosz' Variable-Length Integer Encoding

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but it was not invented by Dlugosz. larsmans has posted a link to the code in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your scheme is similar to UTF-8, which is an encoding scheme used for Unicode text data.

The chief difference is that every byte in a UTF-8 stream indicates whether it is a lead or trailing byte, therefore a sequence can be read starting in the middle. With your scheme a missing lead byte will make the rest of the file completely unreadable if a series of such values are stored. And reading such a sequence must start at the beginning, rather than an arbitrary location.

Answer (score 1):

[Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) refers to using fewer bits to store more common data in exchange for using more bits to store less common data.

Comment: No, this is not huffman coding. From that Wiki page: Huffman coding uses a specific method for choosing the representation for each symbol, resulting in a prefix code (sometimes called "prefix-free codes", that is, ''the bit string representing some particular symbol is never a prefix of the bit string representing any other symbol'') that expresses the most common source symbols using shorter strings of bits than are used for less common source symbols.

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn, you specified the probability of a value being used is the inverse of its magnitude (the smaller, the more probable). Based on your assumption, the algorithm is a form of huffman coding. Mind you, that's the general class of algorithm, and not the name of your specific implementation.

Comment: No, the algorithm I presented is in the class of entropy encoding, but it is not a form of Huffman Coding based on any definition / implementation of Huffman coding in Wikipedia. And by the way, your definition of Huffman coding (from the answer) applies to any entropy coding scheme.

Answer (score 0):

**Byte-aligned variable-length encodings** encode values into variable numbers of whole bytes.
Perhaps the most common is Varint, with 1 bit per byte reserved as a "continuation bit".

In particular, given any format with a single "continuation bit" length-bit (plus 7 data bits) per encoded byte, it's possible to create a related format with the *same* bits re-organized into a slightly different arrangement:
pack all the length-signalling bits at the beginning (usually all packed in the first byte),
and pack the data bits into the rest of the first byte (if there's any room left) (and all 8 bits of the following bytes, if any).

Several people people have used such re-arrangement of bits (sometimes combined with other format tweaks) in order to speed up decoding, typically using SIMD-based algorithms,
such as: ["SIMD-Based Decoding
of Posting Lists"](http://stepanovpapers.com/SIMD_Decoding_TR.pdf)

**Length-signalling bits at start:**

"[Imperial varint](https://dcreager.net/a-better-varint/) places all of the continuation bits at the beginning of the encoded value"

[Carl Mastrangelo: Let’s Make a Varint](https://carlmastrangelo.com/blog/lets-make-a-varint)

["Group Varint Encoding"](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//people/jeff/WSDM09-keynote.pdf) goes further:
a single byte prefix stores the 2-bit "lengths" for the following 4 integer values.
Also called [varint-GB](https://lemire.me/blog/2017/09/27/stream-vbyte-breaking-new-speed-records-for-integer-compression/).

[Stream VByte](https://lemire.me/blog/2017/09/27/stream-vbyte-breaking-new-speed-records-for-integer-compression/) goes even further, storing *all* the "lengths" in one place, and *all* the data bytes in a separate location.

**Varint: Length-signalling bit on each byte**

Using the high bit of each byte to indicate "continue" or "stop", and the remaining bits (7 bits of each byte in the sequence) interpreted as plain binary that encodes the actual value:

This sounds like the "Base 128 Varint" as used in [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html).

**related ways of compressing integers**

In summary: this code represents an integer in 2 parts:
A first part in a unary code that indicates how many bits will be needed to read in the rest of the value, and a second part (of the indicated width in bits) in more-or-less plain binary that encodes the actual value.

This particular code "threads" the unary code with the binary code, but other, similar codes pack the complete unary code first, and then the binary code afterwards,
such as [Elias gamma coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding).

I suspect this code is one of the family of "Start/Stop Codes"
as described in:

Steven Pigeon — [Start/Stop Codes](http://www.stevenpigeon.com/Publications/publications/ssc_full.pdf) — Procs. Data Compression Conference 2001, IEEE Computer Society Press, 2001.

Comment: varint is related, using 1 bit per byte, with the final byte having its high bit clear.  This scheme puts the length-signalling bits at the very start, so all in the first byte.  So it's potentially cheaper to decode, just mapping the position of the first zero to a shift count and mask if you loaded a 4 or 8-byte chunk starting at the first byte.